# Restarting Thin daemon with Capistrano: error: /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I included this simple command on my capistrano deployment with rails.

```
run "/etc/rc.d/thin restart"
```

but the problem is when I deploy I get this error

/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

which is weird because if I manually type /etc/rc.d/thin restart in the server it actually works fine.

It might be worth noting that I added this

set :default_shell, '/bin/bash -l' on my capistrano file though it's weird since I can make the thin restart work if I manually type it on the server with the same user.

Gem versions are:

```
capistrano (2.15.4)
rvm-capistrano (1.4.4)
```

I'm a bit stomped on what's causing the error.

Comment: Could you please provide your `/etc/rc.d/thin`?

Comment: #!/bin/sh

DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@pharmacyqc-admin/bin/thin
SCRIPT_NAME=/etc/rc.d/thin
CONFIG_PATH=/etc/thin

[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
  start)
        $DAEMON start --all $CONFIG_PATH;;
  stop)
        $DAEMON stop --all $CONFIG_PATH;;
  restart)
        $DAEMON restart --all $CONFIG_PATH;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 3;;
esac: